# I can't create a fork on Github

Tags: github, git-fork

I have a repository and I want to create a fork, but there is no option to create a fork, and not only for me, but for another person as well. If I am trying to create a fork from someone else's repository, then I have the option to create a fork.

repository - https://github.com/rovh/Noter

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1280 is specifically left open because there's no way to disable forking on public repo.

Comment: FWIW I see the fork button in the upper right corner and can make a fork. Can you show us a screenshot, please?

Answer (score 0):

What is your role in the repo? base of [this git document](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-repository)

> People with admin permissions for a repository can manage the forking policy for the repository